# Minimalist posters - Can you find the movie?

Tags: visual, movies

> - Let's watch your favorite movie !
>   - If you can guess what it is ! It's hidden in this five minimalist posters
>   - But I don't have time to watch 5 movies...
>   - Oh don't worry there's only one !

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Can you help me find out my friend's favorite movie ?

Comment: Nicely compiled into a puzzle :c)

Comment: Hmm first poster, all I think of is: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=48TR0vUPQCs

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your friend's favourite film is

> Schindler's List

The posters - pretty sure of these

> Zombieland - credit to Poolsharker
>  Ocean's 11
>  The Silence Of The Lambs
>  Pan's Labyrinth (AKA El laberinto del fauno)
>  The Matrix

Because

> "Oh don't worry there's only one!" is a hint to it being
>  The Matrix
>
>  ...but the question says, "It's hidden in this five minimalist posters", so is it hidden in the poster for The Matrix?
>
>  The Matrix poster is *only* numbers, and mostly zeros, could this be where the actual film title is hidden?
>  as letters of the alphabet we'd have:
>
> ```
>  . . . . . E . . .
>  . . . B . . . . .
>  . . . . . B . . .
>  . E . . . . . . .
>  . . . . . . . J .
>  . J . . . . . . .
>  . . . .   . . B .
>  . . . C   . . . .
>  . . . .   .   H .
>    . . F   .   . .
>    . . .   .   M 
>    G   .   .   . 
>    E   .   .   . 
>    .   G   .   . 
>    .   .   A   .
> ```
>
> ...but I don't see much there.
>
>  What about if we replacae the positive numbers with the characters from those positions in the film titles we have so far?  There are four other films and four columns with such numbers, so a reasonable guess it to use one film per column, in order.
>  
>  Well, what would you know, if we use ["ZOMBIELAND", "OCEAN'S ELEVEN",'THE SILENCE OF THE LAMBS', "EL LABERINTO DEL FAUNO"] - we get an answer, almost...
>
> ```
>  . . . . . S . . .                  S
>  . . . C . . . . .              C
>  . . . . . H . . .                  H
>  . I . . . . . . .           I
>  . . . . . . . N .                     N
>  . D . . . . . . .           D
>  . . . .   . . L .                       L
>  . . . E   . . . .               E
>  . . . .   .   R .                       R
>    . . '   .   . .               '
>    . . .   .  (S)                        S
>    L   .   .   .             L
>    I   .   .   .             I
>    .   S   .   .                 S
>    .   .   T   .                     T
> ```
>
> It appears the 13 from the fourth column makes a space but I've replaced it with an S, maybe it's El Laberinto**s** Del Fauno, but not according to imdb... still it must be correct - SCHINDLER'(S)LIST

Comment: you are close... imdb original titles might help you !

Comment: Hmm it's Laberinto, not Laberintos...

Comment: Is that correct?

Comment: Congratulation ! I 've made a small mistake in the last poster : I wanted to have a space and a 'S'. I will correct the puzzle and your answer when I can ;)

Comment: Here, http://i.stack.imgur.com/OPqhB.png

Answer (score 5):

Addition to Jonathan Allan's answer.

> I think the first one is Zombieland.  Looks like a dismembered hand and the guy wants his Twinkies.

Comment: Ah, yes, sounds good to me.